# Create custom ImageProvider QML Plugin with CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qml, qt6

I would like to get to work a minimal custom ImageProvider plugin example, where the plugin code is a separate QML module.

I followed this example project by Qt: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/examples/quick/imageprovider?h=6.6
But I tried to separate the plugin code from the main application into its own module.

My problem is that I do not get it to work to actually import the plugin properly.
Currently, the build process fails because the linker can not find some method:
`/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/nVision-app.dir/main.cpp.o: in function _GLOBAL__sub_I__Z16printQtResourcesb': main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x6e): undefined reference to qt_static_plugin_ImgProvPlugin()'`

My directory structure looks like this:

```
CMakeLists.txt
main.cpp
Main.qml
cpp/
  - imgprov/
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - imgprov.cpp
    - imgprov.hpp
    - plugin.cpp
```

Here is my code:
`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21.1)

project(nVision VERSION 0.6.4 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(QT_MIN_VERSION 6.5)
set(APP_TARGET ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}-app)

set(QT_QML_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/qml)

find_package(Qt6 ${QT_MIN_VERSION} REQUIRED COMPONENTS 
    Gui
    Qml
    Quick
    LinguistTools
)

qt_standard_project_setup(REQUIRES ${QT_MIN_VERSION})

qt_add_executable(${APP_TARGET}
    main.cpp
)

file(GLOB QML_SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} *.qml)
qt_add_qml_module(${APP_TARGET}
    URI ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
    QML_FILES ${QML_SOURCES}
)

add_subdirectory(cpp/imgprov)

target_link_libraries(${APP_TARGET} PRIVATE 
    Qt6::Gui
    Qt6::Qml
    Qt6::Quick
)

set_target_properties(${APP_TARGET} PROPERTIES
    #MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER company.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    # Create an application bundle on macOS.
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    # Prevent the creation of a console window on Windows.
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS ${APP_TARGET}
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

qt_generate_deploy_app_script(
    TARGET ${APP_TARGET}
    OUTPUT_SCRIPT deploy_script
    NO_UNSUPPORTED_PLATFORM_ERROR
)
install(SCRIPT ${deploy_script})
```

`main.cpp`:

```
...
// Add qml module plugins.
#include <QtQml/QQmlExtensionPlugin>
Q_IMPORT_QML_PLUGIN(ImgProvPlugin)
...
```

`Main.qml`

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Controls.Material
import QtQuick.Layouts

import ImgProv

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root

    width: 1920
    height: 1080
    visible: true

    Image {
        source: "image://imgprov/test.png"
    }
}
```

`cpp/imgprov/CMakeLists.txt`

```
# Define the target name.
set(MODULE_TARGET imgprovplugin)

# Create a new QML module.
file(GLOB HEADERS RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} *.hpp)
file(GLOB SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} *.cpp)
qt_add_qml_module(${MODULE_TARGET}
    URI ImgProv
    PLUGIN_TARGET ${MODULE_TARGET}
    NO_PLUGIN_OPTIONAL
    NO_GENERATE_PLUGIN_SOURCE
    CLASS_NAME ImgProvPlugin
    SOURCES ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES}
)

# Link dependencies.
target_link_libraries(${MODULE_TARGET} PRIVATE 
    Qt6::Core 
    Qt6::Gui 
    Qt6::Quick
    Qt6::Qml
)
```

`cpp/imgprov/imgprov.hpp`:

```
#pragma once

#include <QString>
#include <QSize>
#include <QImage>
#include <QThreadPool>
#include <QQuickImageResponse>
#include <QQuickAsyncImageProvider>

// The actual image provider class.
// We subclass the async variant to enforce loading in a low-priority thread,
// regardless of the type of image being requested.
class ImgProv : public QQuickAsyncImageProvider {
public:
    QQuickImageResponse* requestImageResponse(const QString& id, const QSize& requestedSize) override;

private:
    QThreadPool m_threadPool;
};

// The asynchronous image response object.
class AsyncImageResponse : public QQuickImageResponse {
public:
    AsyncImageResponse(const QString& id, const QSize& requestedSize, QThreadPool *pool);

    void handleDone(QImage image);

    QQuickTextureFactory* textureFactory() const override;

private:
    QImage m_image;
};

// The thread implementation of the image response.
class AsyncImageResponseRunnable : public QObject, public QRunnable {
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void done(QImage image);

public:
    AsyncImageResponseRunnable(const QString& id, const QSize& requestedSize)
        : m_id(id), m_requestedSize(requestedSize) {}

    void run();

private:
    QString m_id;
    QSize m_requestedSize;
};
```

`cpp/imgprov/imgprov.cpp`:

```
#include "imgprov.hpp"

//###############//
//### ImgProv ###//
//###############//

QQuickImageResponse* ImgProv::requestImageResponse(const QString& id, const QSize& requestedSize) {
    return new AsyncImageResponse(id, requestedSize, &m_threadPool);
}

//##########################//
//### AsyncImageResponse ###//
//##########################//

AsyncImageResponse::AsyncImageResponse(const QString& id, const QSize& requestedSize, QThreadPool *pool) {
    AsyncImageResponseRunnable* runnable = new AsyncImageResponseRunnable(id, requestedSize);
    connect(runnable, &AsyncImageResponseRunnable::done, this, &AsyncImageResponse::handleDone);
    pool->start(runnable);
}

void AsyncImageResponse::handleDone(QImage image) {
    m_image = image;
    emit finished();
}

QQuickTextureFactory* AsyncImageResponse::textureFactory() const {
    return QQuickTextureFactory::textureFactoryForImage(m_image);
}

//##################################//
//### AsyncImageResponseRunnable ###//
//##################################//

void AsyncImageResponseRunnable::run() {
    QImage image(50, 50, QImage::Format_RGB32);
    
    if (m_id == QLatin1String("slow")) {
        image.fill(Qt::red);
    } else {
        image.fill(Qt::blue);
    }
    if (m_requestedSize.isValid())
        image = image.scaled(m_requestedSize);

    emit done(image);
}
```

`cpp/imgprov/plugin.cpp`:

```
#include "imgprov.hpp"

#include <QQmlExtensionPlugin>

class ImgProvPlugin : public QQmlEngineExtensionPlugin {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID QQmlEngineExtensionInterface_iid)

public:
    void initializeEngine(QQmlEngine *engine, const char *uri) final {
        Q_UNUSED(uri);
        engine->addImageProvider("imgprov", new ImgProv);
    }
};

// This must come after the declaration of our plugin class!
#include "plugin.moc"
```

Comment: Is there anything specific about a QQuickImageProvider in this question? Would you have the same difficulty with any plugin?

Comment: I think it is not related to QQuickImageProvider per se, probably the structure in general. I have not tried to incorporate other plugins yet

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem, but with the CMake provided I don't even get to the linking step. It fails to even configure with error message: "Target "imgprovplugin" of type MODULE_LIBRARY may not be linked into another target.  One may link only to INTERFACE, OBJECT, STATIC or SHARED libraries, or to executables with the ENABLE_EXPORTS property set." Can you please check that this example indeed reproduces the problem, and if it does add the necessary build steps to the question?

Comment: I tried removing `imgprovplugin` from the `target_link_libraries(${APP_TARGET} PRIVATE` call, and now I can reproduce the problem. Your code expects a static plugin, but you're building a dynamic plugin. The question now is: Which one do you want? A proper dynamic plugin or a static plugin compiled into your application?

Comment: Ah thank you for attending my problem and you are right. Between all the different configs I've tried, I have pasted the wrong example here. I edited my question.

I would have liked to build the plugin statically.